# Is it possible to allocate certain required memory and CPU for a C# application, so that it does not freeze when CPU usage is sometimes 100%?

Tags: c#, logging, memory, cpu-usage

I am creating a C# logger application where logging is very crucial and it cannot freeze even when the CPU usage is as high as 100%. Since the memory in the production site is only 4GB, when a CPU intensive task (such as zipping, running some tools) is run, the logger (even though it is a very lightweight application), it tends to freeze and lose network connection, thus trying to re-connect over and over.

So far, I have tried to run the logger application with full admin privilege but no success so far.

So, is there a way allocate some special memory and priority to this logger application so that it keeps running in the background and never freeze?

Comment: You can set the process priority in windows. you can do it programmatically if you wish, or in your own code, also if you were to run this in containers you have a lot of fine grained control over resources

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the process priorities. Actually the executable of this C# logger application is scheduled to run in the server when the system starts (by task scheduler). So that it is always running. And the priority is set to max and has admin privilege. But that didn't help either.

Comment: Are you sure that the network disconnections are caused by high cpu/ram usage? That shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @Steeeve I can't confirm that. Whenever there is high cpu usage, the logger complains that connection is lost and tries to reconnect. The re-connection also becomes successful for a while but then it starts to lose connection again and this process starts over and over, as long as the cpu usage is high. Any clue how to resolve this kind of issue?

Comment: @Binay what are those disconnections more precisely?